# Getting Error creating bean with name

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I'm creating a Spring MVC Maven module based project so I have divided every layer into a maven module. When I try to run a basic site, code compiles fine but I get the error:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'addressController' defined in file [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\wtpwebapps\croz-web\WEB-INF\classes\hr\croz\bspoljaric\controller\AddressController.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect bean class [hr.croz.bspoljaric.controller.AddressController] for resource metadata: could not find class that it depends on
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:525)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4851)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect bean class    [hr.croz.bspoljaric.controller.AddressController] for resource metadata: could not find class that it depends on
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findResourceMetadata(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:344)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:297)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:953)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lhr/croz/bspoljaric/service/AddressService;
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredFields(ReflectionUtils.java:715)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalFields(ReflectionUtils.java:656)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildResourceMetadata(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:361)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findResourceMetadata(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:340)
... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:      hr.croz.bspoljaric.service.AddressService
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
... 30 more
```

AddressDao.java

```
package hr.croz.bspoljaric.dao;

import java.util.List;

import hr.croz.bspoljaric.entity.Address;

public interface AddressDAO {

public void save(Address address);

public void delete(int addressID);

public Address get(int contactId);

public List<Address> getAll();
}
```

AddressDaoImpl.java

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import hr.croz.bspoljaric.dao.AddressDAO;
import hr.croz.bspoljaric.entity.Address;

@Repository
public class AddressDAOImpl implements AddressDAO{

@Override
public void save(Address address) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void delete(int addressID) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public Address get(int contactId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public List<Address> getAll() {
        List<Address> as = new ArrayList<>();
        Address a = new Address();
        a.setId(1l);
        a.setStreet("MAKSIMIRSKA");
        a.setStreetNo("2");
        a.setCity(null);
        as.add(a);
        System.out.println("TEST: " + as.get(1));
        return as;

}

}
```

AddressService.java

```
package hr.croz.bspoljaric.service;

import java.util.List;

import hr.croz.bspoljaric.entity.Address;

public interface AddressService {

public List<Address> getAll();

}
```

AddressServiceImpl.java

```
package hr.croz.bspoljaric.serviceimpl;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import hr.croz.bspoljaric.dao.AddressDAO;
import hr.croz.bspoljaric.entity.Address;
import hr.croz.bspoljaric.service.AddressService;

@Service
public class AddressServiceImpl implements AddressService {
@Autowired
AddressDAO dao;

public List<Address> getAll() {
    return dao.getAll();

}
}
```

AddressController.java

```
package hr.croz.bspoljaric.controller;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;



import hr.croz.bspoljaric.service.AddressService;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class AddressController {

@Autowired
AddressService ads;

@RequestMapping(value = "/getAll", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAllAddresses(Model model)
{
  model.addAttribute("addresses", ads.getAll());
  System.out.println("TEST!");
  return "addressesListDisplay";

 }


 }
```

web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">
<display-name>Croz Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="hr.croz.bspoljaric" />


<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Project view(all except web module):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvyGL.jpg

Project view(web module):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBbgU.jpg)

Comment: The class hr.croz.bspoljaric.service.AddressService is missing in the classpath of your app. You need to fix the way you're creating the war, and make sure all the necessary jar files are stored in its WEB-INF/lib directory. What matters is your pom file here. Not the code.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm clearly missing something because I declared in web pom file the dependency on service. These are my pom files: 1. Web: http://pastebin.com/ZSLjzx8Z ; 2. parent: http://pastebin.com/NXMnzCbH ; 3. service: http://pastebin.com/zHCPfuc1

Answer (score 5):

You need to `mvn clean install` in parent module to install the other module to local repo before you run your web module alone.

Or you can `mvn clean install -am` in web module, so that it will build the depended modules.

Please change the packaging to jar in service module, or just remove it, the default packaging is jar.

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>croz-service</name>
```

Comment: Hey, I have ran maven install and everything went trough, but still I get the error.

Comment: worked for me thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Go to the folder which contains the project pom file. Then get the cmd and run**

```
mvn clean install
```

[image] If it is failed, try it after deleting the target folder